# How to merge/concat two JSON files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In some questions here in stackoverflow show how to merge two JSON objects from inner HTML or in a var but I want to merge two external JSON files or URLs with JSON response.

Here an exemple with local vars: http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/agp54/

```
var object1 = {name: "John"};
var object2 = {location: "San Jose"};

var objectA = $.extend({}, object1, object2);
//var objectB = object1.concat(object2);

console.log(objectA);
```

Then I will get my JSON like this or similar:

```
jQuery.getJson("data.json", function(data){...};
```

Any hint for concat my two JSONs: `json1.json` and `json2.json`? :)

Comment: You mean merge the JSON after getting those files?

Comment: yeah: "with great precision and thinking about how to deal with conflicts". What does "merge" mean when you have `{a:"one"}` and `{a:"two"}`, for instance? If "a" is "latest published", then maybe you want to keep only the second value. If it's not, maybe you need the first? Or an array of both values? You can't "merge" unless you know the data's model, so that'd be task 1: find out what the JSON's model is, and validate it against that so your notion of what merging means applies.

Comment: Yes @Vega. For example I have two JSON files like:
Joe, Walker
Jon,Terry

And other JSON like the same but I will to concat the content.

Comment: Describe the problem in detail. Obviously the merging will be identical. So what's the issue? Is it that you want to make both JSON requests at the same instead of sequentially?'

Comment: The merge/concat is the issue. I want merge similar JSON that it come in different files.

Comment: to merge 2 document object you need to read them. the best way is to do something like this :var object = $.extend({}, object1, object2);
that decision is very specific and you neet to do it by yourself.

Comment: @Lins: You're already getting the objects and parsing them by using `$.getJSON`, and you already know how to merge them once you get them using `$.extend()`, so I don't see what the problem is. Are you saying you want to convert it back to JSON when done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there.  You just need to re-serialize after you do the extend.

```
  var a = '{"foo": 1}';
  var b = '{"bar": 2}';

  var combined = $.extend({}, 
                         JSON.parse(a),
                         JSON.parse(b));

  var serialized = JSON.stringify(combined);
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can merge two objects with

```
jQuery.getJson("data.json", function(data) {
    jQuery.getJson("data2.json", function(data2) {
        var concatenatedJson = $.extend({}, data, data2);
    });
});
```

So that you can of course only do, after both json objects are loaded.